# Exporting result of select statement to CSV format in DB2

Tags: csv, db2, export

Is there any way by which we can export the result of a select statment to CSV file, just like in MySQL.

MySQL Command;

```
SELECT col1,col2,coln into OUTFILE  'result.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' FROM testtable t;
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can run this command from the DB2 command line processor (CLP) or from inside a SQL application by calling the `ADMIN_CMD` stored procedure

```
EXPORT TO result.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL 
SELECT col1, col2, coln FROM testtable;
```

There are lots of options for `IMPORT` and `EXPORT` that you can use to create a data file that meets your needs. The `NOCHARDEL` qualifier will suppress double quote characters that would otherwise appear around each character column.

Keep in mind that any `SELECT` statement can be used as the source for your export, including joins or even recursive SQL. The export utility will also honor the sort order if you specify an `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: `DEL` is not supported on zOS DB2.

Comment: is there a way to EXPORT to csv and include the headers in the output file?

Comment: The EXPORT utility does not produce a header row itself, and it won't append its results to the output file, so anything that was previously in the file (including a header row) will be overwritten. If all of the columns in your result set are CHAR or VARCHAR, your query could use UNION ALL to include a row of column headings, along with an ORDER BY that forces the header row to appear first. Alternatively, if you're using the CLP to run the EXPORT command, you could follow up with a call to an external program such as sed -i to prepend a line of text at the beginning of the output file.

Comment: How If I want to append instead of override the content inside the file?

Comment: Db2's EXPORT utility will always overwrite the output file if it exists. There is no option for EXPORT to append to a file.

Comment: @FredSobotka I have squirrel client and I want to export data as insert statement. How can i do that?

Comment: @AakashPatel Please open a new question for that if you're still looking for an answer

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it from DB2 client.

1. Open the Command Editor and Run the select Query in the Commands Tab.
2. Open the corresponding Query Results Tab
3. Then from Menu --> Selected --> Export

Answer (score 2):

[DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) allows you connect to a DB2 database, run a query, and export the result-set to a CSV file that can be opened and fine-tuned in MS Excel or [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/).

To do this, all you have to do (in [DBeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/)) is right-click on the results grid (after running the query) and select "Export Resultset" from the context-menu.

This produces the dialog below, where you can ultimately save the result-set to a file as CSV, XML, or HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html), you want to export of type del (the default delimiter looks like a comma, which is what you want).  See the doc page for more information on the EXPORT command.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and got a ';'-delimited csv file:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR % 
EXPORT TO result.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY CHARDEL;
SELECT * FROM A
```

Comment: The `CHARDEL` modifier specifies the character that encloses any string values in the row. Its default is `"`. To change the delimiter that goes between columns, use the `COLDEL` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using IBM Data Studio v 3.1.1.0 with an underlying DB2 for z/OS and the accepted answer didn't work for me.
If you're using IBM Data Studio (v3.1.1.0) you can:

1. Expand your server connection in "Administration Explorer" view;
2. Select tables or views;
3. On the right panel, right click your table or view;
4. There should be an option to extract/download data, in portuguese it says: "Descarregar -> Com sql" - something like "Download -> with sql;"